# Vue: Data only passed to child on first render when I change console log, gets deleted on refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, lifecycle

I'm passing data from one file (store.js) to another (Home.vue), then trying to pass that data as props into a child component (Cards).

For some reason, the data doesn't get passed from store to Home on first render. However, if I edit the console.log - even just one character in the accompanying string - then the data comes in and updates my state. If I refresh, we go back to square one.

I've tried doing this with both created() and mounted(), and added a v-if to check if the data was loaded before rendering.

Here's the relevant code:

store.js

```
const store = {
  pictures: null,
};

mariaCollection.onSnapshot((mariaRef) => {
  const data = [];
  mariaRef.forEach((doc) => {
    const instance = doc.data();
    instance.id = doc.id;
    data.push(instance);
  });
  store.pictures = data;
  console.log(store.pictures);
});

export { mariaCollection, db, Timestamp, GeoPoint, store };
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
    <Cards v-if="dataLoaded" v-bind:imageData="pictures" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { store } from "../db";
import Cards from "../components/Cards";

export default {
  components: {
    Cards,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      test: "test",
      family: "",
      pictures: null,
      dataLoaded: false,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.pictures = store.pictures;
    console.log("created " + JSON.stringify(store.pictures));
    this.dataLoaded = true;
  },
};
</script>
```

Accompanying image of my console:

[image: console log order]

Comment: hmm maybe your mariadb snapshot is not ready already. Is it a async function thats takes time to execute? Maybe the created and mounted hooks ran before the db snapshot comes in. So it is null. When Vue is doing the hot reload the variable is filled an the created hook works like expected. You can even proof this behaviour in your console screenshot. The console log of your data appears AFTER your created console.log.